# Floating side value of a swap

Tags: valuation

I have some trouble to understand on valuing the floating side of a swap.
In my book, the value of floating side at the time t is;

$$ P(t,T_0) - P(t,T_n) $$

Where $$  P(t,T_n)$$ denotes the value of zero coupon bond at time t which payoff $1 at the maturity.
However, there are no additional explanation about this and I think that I'm missing some point at this swap valuation process.
I think that floating side should pay floating rate at every reset moment, so above formula is not intuitive for me.

May I ask what is missing on this valuation?